# How can I insert spaces in a table (lua)

Tags: string, lua

I'm trying to insert spaces in a table to make ASCII art but everytime I try to do so, lua considers this string: " " as empty despite having a space in it.

No matter what I do, lua won't allow me to use a string containing only spaces. (Yes, even multiple spaces). How can I fix this?

Comment: Show your code that isn't working.

Comment: Your premise is wrong; `" " ~= ""` in Lua. Lua does *not* distinguish strings with a space in them as empty strings. Show your code, because your bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, my compiler was the problem the entire time.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small test and seems to be working fine here.

```
local t = {
    blah = "hello"
}

function string.insert(originalString, insertString, position)
    position = math.min(math.max(position, 1), #originalString + 1)
    return originalString:sub(1, position - 1) .. insertString .. originalString:sub(position)
end

print("Before -> " ..t.blah)
t.blah = t.blah:insert(" ", 3)
print("After -> " ..t.blah)

-- output: Before -> hello
-- output: After -> he llo
```

Comment: Oops, I meant inserting a string only containing spaces (like this: "           ") in a table, not inserting a space in a string in a table.

Comment: `like this: " "` That IS a space in a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use string method `rep()`

```
-- columns.lua
local cols = 80 -- Amount of spaces
local tab = {} -- A Table
local space = "\32" -- Byte for a Space

table.insert(tab, space:rep(cols)) -- Insert it with length of cols time

print(tab[#tab] .. 'END') -- Show it
-- Output:                                                                                END
```